# On Text Change in a Column DataGridView Search In DataBase And put result to other Column

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView and Columns set manualy
Look like this: 
[image]

I need this :
When BarCode Entered in Column BarCode ,  Search in DataBase and put Result in ProductName

I tried this but it does not work:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value) != "")
    {
        DataTable dtl = new DataTable();
        _id = Int32.Parse(Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value));
        dtl = dc.RunQuery(@"SELECT ProductName FROM Product WHERE ProductCode = '" + _id + "'");
        DataRow row = dtl.Rows[0];
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value = row[0].ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `CellValueChanged` event to acheive what you want, something like,

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    string currentValue = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value);
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentValue))
    {
        Int32.TryParse(currentValue, out _id);
        DataTable dtl = dc.RunQuery(@"SELECT ProductName FROM Product WHERE ProductCode = '" + _id + "'");
        DataRow row = dtl.Rows[0];
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value = row[0].ToString();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps...